# Using synchronous input along with asynchronous input at the same time in a flip flop

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop

For example let us consider an SR flip flop.

If the clear input is 0 (active low) and preset is 1 this will force the output to go to reset condition (Q=0 and Q'=1.) But if the clear=0 and Preset =1 in this state we give set=1, reset=0 and clock =1 then will both the output be 1 and 1?

If so then using the overriding input when clock =1 is a problem. How to deal with this problem?

[image: SR flip flop]

Comment: Q'=1 (that was a typo) and Q can be either 1 or 0 so if both outputs are 1 then that causes a problem.How to get rid of this problem as one should be the compliment of the another

Comment: It's not a 'problem', it's the behaviour of that circuit. If you don't want that behaviour, then either avoid those input conditions, or use a different circuit with a different behaviour. Perhaps use a circuit with an inverter on the Q output to give the Qbar output. That would guarrantee that Q and Qbar are always complements, except for the few nS of the inverter propagation delay.

Comment: So if the clear input is pressed regardless of the input of the S and R the output will be Q'=1 and Q=0 is false?

Comment: PRE is kept at 1

Comment: please review the NAND gate .... you would not be asking the question in your comment if the operation of the NAND gate was clear in your head

Comment: any low input to a NAND gate produces a high output ... `regardless of the input of the S and R` makes the statement false

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to deal with this. You could, for example, ignore the \$\overline{Q}\$ output and use only the \$Q\$ output. If you really need the complement then add an inverter.

You could also design the logic **around** the latch to eliminate the possibility that the asynchronous inputs could be asserted while the enable is also asserted. A better idea might be to prevent the enable from being asserted while either of the asynchronous inputs is asserted. The best approach depends entirely on how you intend to **use** the latch, and which inputs you want to be prioritized over the others.

By the way, the circuit you present is not an edge-sensitive circuit, it is a level-sensitive circuit. That's why it has an \$enable\$ input rather than an actual \$clock\$ input. I think most of us here would call that a **latch** rather than a **flip-flop**.

Comment: the problem remains regardless of the input being enable/ pulse transition detector to detect an edge.

Comment: So if the clear input is pressed regardless of the input of the S and R the output will be Q'=1 and Q=0 is false?

Comment: Look at it this way: If CLR is low then Q' **must** be high, regardless of any other inputs. If PR is low then Q **must** be high, regardless of any other inputs. So your last statement "clear input is pressed regardless of...S and R..." **can not be answered** without specifying the value of PR. You really need to make a truth table.

Comment: PRE is set to 1 which is always done as both PRE and CLR can't be 0 at the same time

Comment: if i update it , if the clear input is pressed(0 active low) and preset is kept 1 regardless of the input of the S and R the output will be Q'=1 and Q=0 is false?

Comment: No, you can't ignore the enable input. Make a truth table!

Comment: How do you know that PR and CLR can not be 0 at the same time, but you don't know if enable can be high while one of them is low?

Comment: your missing the point the statement is simple Pre=1 CLR=0 ClK=1 S=1 R= 0  now i have seen a statement that the PRE and CLR is overriding input , the S and R along with clock does not matter when they are pressed.The output will always be Q=1 and Qnot=0 if CLR is pressed and PRE is 1

Comment: Is this statement wrong or not?

Comment: Do you mean this statement (paraphrased from your last sentence): If PR=1 and CLR=0 then it must be true that Q=1 and Q'=0. That statement is wrong. Make a truth table. Stop saying "pressed" and say 0 or 1. Stop talking about "clock" and start talking about "enable".

Answer (score -1):

First of all we have to know about little bit about latches after we going to flipflop..
Basically they are such as:
SR, RS
JK
D
T-flipflops

Simple in SR --flipflop first we have to see what components we used in f/f. Basically 4 nand gates with combination of latches with clock pulse is constant with 1.
Now we have to check by some methods.
Basically.
Is drawback of SR-F/F.
We basically change clk pulse..
But only we deal to overcome with this situation by using JK-Flipflop..

Comment: this has nothing to do with my question

Comment: In SR F/F  both Q and Qnot are not same...

Comment: No, it is not true that Q and Q' can not be the same, not for the simple cross-coupled NAND or NOR latch.

Comment: Yes that is the drawback of SR F/F

Comment: Overcome by JK f/f

Comment: We're talking about a latch here, not a flip-flop. And there are better choices than a JK. Those are antiques now.